# Is it 'jargon'?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

When a non-native writer writes a paragraph which is difficult to understand because of some errors and unnatural use of the language, could we call this kind of language for example **'a bit jargon'** or 'jargon' is not used this way ?

Comment: No, jargon is used to describe words which are specialized and belong to a particular field or context and are usually difficult for those not familiar with that field to understand. Jargon is correct grammatical English- it just may be a bit obtuse to outsiders.

Comment: *Jargon* is a noun, not an adjective, so *a bit jargon* is syntactically strange.  Informally, you can make it into an adjective with an ending like *-ish*, *-y*, or more properly you can make a compound such as *jargon-laden* or *jargon-heavy*.  (This is all ignoring the question of **meaning**, of course.)

Comment: On a related note, you might be confusing *jargon* with *gibberish*, which would make sense in this case (though it's also a noun, as @snailboat pointed out.) In this situation you could say "This whole essay is full of gibberish."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Jargon is not "incorrect". It may be unnatural use of expressions that mean something else in other circumstances, but it is not *wrong* use. It's *special* use.

Jargon usually uses specialist words that fit within given narrow domain of expertise, but it frequently borrows words from "mainstream" giving them new meanings, and this could cause a lot of confusion.

When you *fork a thread to bang bits over the bus*, it has nothing to do with skewering a sewing material with an eating utensil in order to hammer small pieces above a public transport vehicle. It's jargon for making a simultaneously running duplicate of a certain program running in the computer memory, and assigning the duplicate a task of sending zeros or ones one after another in specific sentence through a connector that connects multiple devices. But as you can see, telling this in non-jargon way is overly verbose and pointlessly delves into details any professional in the field doesn't need repeated.

Answer (score 2):

Jargon is *never* used to refer to unnatural or incorrect use of language by non-native speakers. It refers to words and phrases that are very specialized to some area of business, science, or technology. "I can't read this because it's full of computer jargon." "Can't we have a conversation without you using medical jargon?"